# Converting Unicode to text in Java

Tags: java, unicode

What I have here is a unicode.txt file that contains numbers (The first line of the .txt file "82 117 109 112 101 108 115 116 105 108 116 115 107 105 110"). I want to convert this Unicode into normal text. The thing is that instead of doing that, the unicode.txt file is duplicated into the text.txt file. I'm new to java so hopefully, someone could help me and I apologize in advance if some other parts of my code are incorrect or if my explanation was not understandable.

```
public static void translator(String a) throws IOException{
    a = "unicode.txt";
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(a));
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("text.txt");
    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        String fileL = inputFile.nextLine();
        for(int h = 0; h < fileL.length(); h++){
            char y = fileL.charAt(h);
            outputFile.print(y);
        }
        outputFile.println();
    }
    outputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean int char to ascii? `char ch = (char) yourInt` or 
`String str = String.valueOf(yourInt);`

Comment: There are lots of article available on the internet which can provide you some in depth about the topic. try http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with Unicode

Comment: Also, `charAt` is not what you want, if you want to consume each individual number. Such as `82` rather than `8` and then a `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method only reads in the characters of the input file one digit by one digit and then writes it to the output file without any modification.

If you want to read in the whole number instead of the digits, you need to use `nextInt()` instead.

i.e.

```
while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
    int asciiCode = inputFile.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

And to convert asciiCode to char, you may use

```
char c = (char) asciiCode;
```